# Updating specific rows of one data frame using another, without non-specifically overwriting other entries (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I'd like to use df1 to update df2, to produce a data frame that looks like df3. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c("D-10003","D-10004"), date=c(2,2), length=c(22,45))
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c("D-10001","D-10003","D-10002","D-10004","D-10005"), date=c(1,NA,NA,NA,2), hair=c(2,3,NA,2,3))
df3 <- data.frame(ID=c("D-10001","D-10003","D-10002","D-10004","D-10005"), date=c(1,2,NA,2,2),hair=c(2,3,NA,2,3))
```

I've been trying various variations on this, but it always seems to overwrite legitimate entries (eg for ID D-10001, date should remain 1), and I have no clue as to why.

```
df2$date<-df1[match(df2$ID, df1$ID),2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df2$date[is.na(df2$date)] <- df1$date[match(df2$ID[is.na(df2$date)],df1$ID)]`

Comment: This is my go to solution for matching situations, I would note that this looks for the first match, not all matches. So, for example, if you had D-10004 twice in df1 with two different date values, it would only map over the first date value.

Comment: @D.sen Absolutely yep.  Probably should have commented that myself.  Beware the duplicates.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
sapply(dt1$ID,function(x)dt2$date[dt2$ID==x]<<-dt1$date[dt1$ID==x])
```

PS: no need to use assinging to anything. It's being assgined from within the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df2[df1, date := df1$date, on = c(ID = "ID")]
#         ID date hair
# 1: D-10001    1    2
# 2: D-10003    2    3
# 3: D-10002   NA   NA
# 4: D-10004    2    2
# 5: D-10005    2    3
```

As in the first posted answer, there's no need for assignment, as `df2` is modified in-place.

Here's another option that protects against overwriting non-NA values, even if the IDs match:

```
df2[df1, `:=` (date = ifelse(is.na(date), df1$date, date)), on = c(ID = "ID")]
```